connect to a database on sqlite3 terminal
I opened sqlite3.exe application located in this folder:
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\bin
The terminal comes up with the following prompt:
sqlite>
I have my my.db file located in C:\Users\myname\Desktop\sqlite-python
How do I run this code to connect to my database?
sqlite3 my.db

when I tried a few variation of the above code I kept getting new line of ...> in the terminal.

See https://sqlite.org/cli.html
